# Dynamic Pages & SEO Friendly URL in sitemap

Tags: seo, sitemap, c#

I have a website built with C# that has some dynamic pages.  And I've recently added some code to allow using SEO friendly URLs.  (if you know C#, I'm using Context.RewritePath(....) to do it)

For example, normally my page Url would be: "/products.aspx?itID=1" but with the new code you can access it with "/Product-Name" as well.

Should I be putting the SEO Friendly URL in my sitemap instead of the regular URL?  I think the answer is yes, but I'm very new to this and would really appreciate some confirmation from someone with more experience.

My reasoning is that google prefers a Url like "fruits/green-apple" over "product.aspx?fID=1", right?

EDIT: Tried to be more precise.

Comment: What makes one of those URLs more "real" than the other one?

Comment: Having multiple URLs that can load the same content is not good for SEO.  Besides creating a sitemap, what are you doing to mitigate the duplicate content issues from having two sets of URLs?  Are you redirecting from one to the other?  Are you using canonical tags?  Are you linking consistently to one of them?

Comment: Well, product.aspx is the actual name of the file so i consider that one as real, whereas /Product-Name would be a string I created for each product and it basically redirects to product.aspx.    (Im using Context.RewritePath(.....) to show the proper content.

From what I read, I'm thinking of using canonical tags. And also, I will be going through my website shortly to change all current links to link to the equivalent friendly URL instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use friendly URLs (which a fine idea), go all the way. Make sure that all links on your site use them, *including the sitemap*.

Then, as Stephen touched on, either use 301 redirects or canonical tags so that if any crawlers visit your non-friendly URLs, they are pointed to the canonical page.